# I need help understanding bit order in DES for a C implementation

Tags: encryption, des

I'm using a variety of references to study this algorithm, among others Christof Paar's book and classes. Currently I'm working on a custom C implementation of the algorithm, and am trying to implement ***the Expansion function*** in DES.

I am having problems with bit order. In an example provided in this [link](https://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/edi051/projects/des/des.pdf), the following data (A) gets expanded to (B):

```
(b<x>) --> byte <x>

   (b0) (b1) (b2) (b3)
A: 0xF0 0xAA 0xF0 0xAA

   (b0)                    (b5)
B: 0x7A 0x15 0x55 x7A 0x15 0x55
```

At a bit level, what's happening is:

```
A:   1111   0000   1010   1010
B:  011110 100001 010101 01010-

    0111 1010 0001 0101 0101...
    0x7  0xA  0x1  0x5  0x5...
```

Now, unless I'm missing something, I'd say that in byte 0xF0, or 0b11110000, the left-most bit (1) is being treated as bit 0, and the right-most bit (0), is being treated as bit 7.

This is, however, opposite to the bit order offered by C. In C, bit 0 is the right-most, and bit 7 is the left-most. The expansion of this byte would look like:

```
 0000   1111
100001 01111...
```

Am I missing something? What bit order - endianness should I be considering in this algorithm?

Comment: Its not really cut in stone from which end you number your bits. In the document you link to, they actually start with 1 from left (not 0). Also C don't really give you a way to pinpoint a single bit by an index ..

Comment: This question [_Initial Permutation of DES_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/62683/555) and its answer may help. It also links to the spec.